# Azure Active Directory EXTERNAL GROUP - The specified schema name either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

So I have set up a security group [PERMISSIONS-TEST] in Azure Active Directory and added users to this group. I've also created the EXTERNAL GROUP in the target Azure SQL database. I'm able to authenticate, query and create tables using the Active Directory login, but cannot create a schema. When I execute this command `create schema test` I get the following error

`Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The specified schema name testuser@testorg.onmicrosoft.com" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. Msg 2759, Level 16, State 0, Line 6 CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous errors`

The EXTERNAL GROUP has the following permissions:

- principal_id  name    type_desc   authentication_type_desc    state_desc  permission_name
- 15    PERMISSIONS-TEST    EXTERNAL_GROUP  EXTERNAL    GRANT   CONNECT
- 15    PERMISSIONS-TEST    EXTERNAL_GROUP  EXTERNAL    GRANT   CREATE SCHEMA
- 15    PERMISSIONS-TEST    EXTERNAL_GROUP  EXTERNAL    GRANT   EXECUTE

I've also granted dbo as the default schema to this group.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you grant create schema as `GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO [your AAD group]` and try creating schema?

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT I have tried this, but get the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) from this CREATE SCHEMA documentation.

Also, there is a similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193354/second-member-of-azure-ad-group-can-not-create-schema-in-azure-sql-database) thread related to the same issue.

Comment: Please post this as a comment, rather than an answer. Link-only answers are not valid answers. And if you feel that the similar SO question is the same basic question, you should flag the question here as a duplicate, rather than just posting a link.